# In Javascript how can I change an alert window to display that alert next to an input box

Tags: javascript, cell, alert

My friend and I are making a data validation program. If you enter in data that the program will not accept (example such as putting numbers in a name field) you get a windows alert telling you that is not valid. We decided we want to change this so that instead of a windows alert there will be an empty table cell to the right of each of the form elements that displays that your data is not valid. How could I change this? Attaching code below.

```
function fNameValidation()
{
if (document.forms[0].fName.value.length==0)                //First name data validation
{                                                           //check for any entry
alert('Please enter your first name.');
document.forms[0].fName.focus();
return;
}
```

Comment: What's the relevant HTML of the `<table>`, and the `<input>`s?

Answer (score 0):

Place a span element next to your input field with a unique ID,
Then you can insert Text into that specific field:

```
document.getElementById('firstNameError').innerHTML = "Please enter your first name.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest aproach is to set id of this cell:

```
<td id="nameErrorCell">
    (...)
</td>
```

and than in your javascript:

```
var cell = document.getElementById('nameErrorCell');
cell.innerHTML="error message";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also traverse DOM tree up one level to `<td>` element, then to its sibling and alter its `innerHTML` with your error message.

```
document.forms[0].fName.parentNode.nextSibling.innerHTML = 'Please enter your first name.');
```

If there are elements between `<input>` and `<td>`, add more `.parentNode`.